# CSS move one letter from text

Tags: css, animation, transition

Is there a way to move one letter from a word in CSS?
So first there is this evenly spaced word. Then for example the first letter of the word moves 10px left, but the rest of the word stays where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::first-letter` selector in CSS like [in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/1czzecyv/)

```
p::first-letter {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Since you want to animate this, I've updated [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1czzecyv/6/) with this code :

You can't use ::first-letter with animate so I use a `<span>` inside a `<p>` element

HTML :

```
<p>
    <span>E</span>xample
</p>
```

CSS :

```
p span {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 1s 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: mymove 1s 1;
  position: relative;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {margin-right: 0;}
    100% {margin-right: 10px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {margin-right: 0;}
    100% {margin-right: 10px;}
}
```

Comment: But is there a way to animate this coming off the word?

Comment: You mean with CSS transitions or keyframes ?

Comment: I was thinking to use keyframes, but whatever is easier.

Comment: I made you an example with keyframes